# wsl2: access denied when trying to login into distro (fixed with wsl shutdown)

Tags: wsl2

I have an ubuntu distro in WSL 2. Actually the problem seems to begin after I moved disto data to another drive (using lxrunoffline).

So after system start, I try to log in to default distro (using `bash` command):

```
> bash
Access is denied.
```

Get the same result with the user and administrator privileges.

Then I do `wsl --shutdown` and it starts to work normally.

OS: Windows 11. (Version    10.0.22631 Build 22631)

Any guess how this could be fixed?

Comment: Do you have the current version of WSL from the Windows Store installed or the legacy version installed? Running the command bash, is the old way, of starting WSL.

Comment: I don't remember how I installed it, it is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Any ay If I do `wsl` command I get the same result. And Docker desktop can not start until I do `wsl --shutdown` after windows startup.

Comment: Do you by chance have installed both the WSL2 version that's installed from the command-line and also the one from the Microsoft Store?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR - Until you can tell us what version of WSL you have we cannot help you

Comment: What do you mean by version of WSL? I believe I've installed it from the store (when I was on Window v10, then I updated the OS to v11). It is  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS - WSL2 distro.